# Integrate ImageMagick & MagickWand with php ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, imagemagick, magickwand

I have installed both ImageMagick and MagickWand in my ubuntu system by refering to the detailed instructions provided in [Install ImageMagick From Source](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php) and [MagickWand For PHP](http://www.magickwand.org/). When I chack whether ImageMagick is installed or not by command `identify -version`, it shows me follwing message

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.7-9 Q16 i686 2013-12-09 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates: bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr openexr pangocairo png tiff x xml zlib
```

That means Image Magick is installed. And When I check the version of MagickWand with `MagickWand-config --version` it also shows me the version number `6.8.7 Q16`.

But problem is when I try to intialize the wrapper class of the MagickWand i.e. `$magick_wand=NewMagickWand();` It shows me the Fatal Error as follows,

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function NewMagickWand()
```

Can somebody tell me where did I make a mistake and how to make it work with php.

Comment: I also have placed the 'magickwand' folder inside /usr/include/php5/ext to use magickwand as an extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$img = new Imagick();
```

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

This seems to have been the fix: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22911

Comment: But it is clearly mentioned [here](http://www.magickwand.org/) that it is for PHP.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that. I edited my answer. It seems that the same issue was encountered by another user?

Comment: this post contains only one answer, and it says that load the magickwand extension, i already have tried that. See my comment in the question. I have tried every possible way, but failed and exhausted.

Comment: Is there something provided by MagickWand for PHP that is not provided by ImageMagick? Can I get more information as to what you're trying to get done?

Comment: I would try this: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22911

Comment: My task is to convert PSD, PDF, TIFF image to PNG files and save both image.* and image.png to database

Comment: ImageMagick can do all of that. I don't think you need to mess around with MagickWand.

Comment: CAn you please suggest some script or reference site to do my task with ImageMagick

Comment: This is all command line processing. I need all this in PHP Script, that's why I am dying to make MagickWand Work for me.

Comment: Finally got it, the link for forum really helped me, put it in yoour answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: Just had missed the last step ie. adding the ini file of magickwand